# Why Go's channel can close twice?

Tags: go, channel

When I am do some go practices code, I encounter a problem that a channel can be closed twice like this:

```
// jobs.go

package main

import (
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    jobs := make(chan int, 5)
    done := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for {
            j,more := <-jobs

            fmt.Println("receive close: ", j, more)
            done <- true   
        }
    }()

    close(jobs)
    <- done
}
```

Output:

```
~ go run jobs.go
Hello, playground
receive close:  0 false
receive close:  0 false
```

But when I close the channel twice manually, I got `panic: close of closed channel`.

Why the code above can receive close  twice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A channel can only be closed once, attempting to close a closed channel panics.

But [receiving](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) from a closed channel is not limited, receiving from a closed channel:

> A receive operation on a [closed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close) channel can always proceed immediately, yielding the element type's [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) after any previously sent values have been received.

A Go app runs until its main goroutine runs (given "normal" circumstances), or from another point of view: a Go app terminates when its main goroutine terminates, that is, the `main()` function returns. It does not wait for other non-`main` goroutines to complete.

You started a 2nd goroutine with an endless `for` loop, with no way of terminating. So that loop will keep going until the `main()` function –which runs in the concurrent, main goroutine– returns. Since the `for` loop first receives from `jobs`, it waits for the main goroutine to close it (this receive operation can only then proceed). Then the main goroutine wants to receive from `done`, so that waits until the 2nd goroutine sends a value on it. Then the main goroutine is "free" to terminate at any moment. Your 2nd goroutine running the loop may receive an additional value from `jobs` since it's closed, but the subsequent send on `done` will block as there are nobody receiving from it anymore (and it's unbuffered).

Receiving from a channel until it's closed is normally done using `for range`, which exits if the channel is closed:

```
for j := range jobs {
    fmt.Println("received: ", j)
    done <- true
}
```

Of course this would cause a deadlock in your case, as the loop body would never be reached as nobody sends anything on `jobs`, and so the loop would never enter its body to send a value on `done` which is what the main goroutine waits for.

Answer (score 1):

The `jobs` channel is not being closed twice. It's closed only once when `close(jobs)` is called. The output you are seeing is because of how the goroutine and main threads are executing.

When the goroutine fires, it does not immidieatly start running. Instead, the program control goes to this part:

```
  close(jobs) // <--
  <- done
}
```

and `jobs` is closed. Main thread then hangs on the next receive on `done`.

Now context switching occurs and the goroutine starts running. It reads from a closed `jobs`, prints the appropriate values (`false` for `more` indicating a closed channel), and sends a `true` along `done`.

However, the loop is able to execute once more and the goroutine blocks on the next send on `done`. Now `main` wakes up again, receives on `done` and terminates the program.

Answer (score 0):

Go channel no getting closed twise. your are passing done <- true after first print

```
j,more := <-jobs

fmt.Println("receive close: ", j, more)
done <- true
```

so it printed two time

```
receive close:  0 false
receive close:  0 false
```

If you use done <- true before print then it will print one time only, will get closed.

```
done <- true
j,more := <-jobs

fmt.Println("receive close: ", j, more)
```

Output :

```
receive close:  0 false
```