# Reading from channel giving SIGSEGV: segmentation violation

Tags: mongodb, go, channel, segmentation-fault

I was trying to insert documents in the mongoDB using go-client (mgo). I create a new mongo session, and two channels for communcaition b/w go-routines, ***channel*** is used to sync b/w ***readFile*** and ***main***, while other is to pass data read from file in ***readFile*** to db write routine  ***insertTxn***.

```
type Txn struct {
    Date time.Time
    Amt  float64
}



func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    channel := make(chan bool)
    txnChannel := make(chan Txn, 1e4)

    go readFile(txnChannel, channel)
    go insertTxn(session, txnChannel)

    <-channel
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10) // waiting for insertTxn to finish

    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println(r)
        }
    }()
}
```

Then, goroutine ***readFile*** is started which starts reading from an input file, and writing the data to ***txnChannel*** channel. After completion, it marks the completion by writing to channel ***channel***.

```
func readFile(txnChannel chan<- Txn, channel chan<- bool) { // write only channel
        txnFile, err := os.Open("path/to/dir/txns.txt")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        txnReader := bufio.NewReader(txnFile)
        defer func() {
            txnFile.Close()
            channel <- true
        }()
        var data []string
        var txn Txn
        var dur int
        var str string
        for i := 0; i < 25*1e2; i++ {
            str, err = txnReader.ReadString('\n')
            str = strings.TrimSuffix(str, "\n")
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            data = strings.Split(str, " ")
            txn.Amt, err = strconv.ParseFloat(data[1], 64)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            dur, err = strconv.Atoi(data[0])
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            txn.Date = time.Now().Add(-time.Second * time.Duration(dur))
            txnChannel <- txn
        }
}
```

The other goroutine ***insertTxn***, creates a reference to txn collection, and keep listening on the ***txnChannel***  channel, and writes the data it receives to the mongo collection.

```
func insertTxn(session *mgo.Session, txnChannel <-chan Txn) {
        txnColl := session.DB("happay").C("txns")
        for {
            select {
            case txn := <-txnChannel:
                if err := txnColl.Insert(txn).Error; err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Now, the program panics with following reason:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x1151f27]
```

I believe the issue might be that I am using the same struct again and again, but as I read that writing to a channel does copy by value, rather than by reference. So, it should work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem is in `insertTxn()` function:

```
if err := txnColl.Insert(txn).Error; err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

`Collection.Insert()` returns a value of type `error`, and you refer to its `Error` method, but you don't call it (calling it would look like `Error()` which would result in a value of type `string` which cannot be compared to `nil` anyway...), so your `err` variable will be a function value, which panics if `Collection.Insert()` returns an explicit `nil` error value.

If you want to check if some function returns an error, don't call its `error.Error()` method, simply check the `error` value itself like this:

```
if err := txnColl.Insert(txn); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

**Some other notes:**

Use `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for goroutines, `time.Sleep()` may be ok for a demo, but it's really bad for "production" code. For an example, see [Prevent the main() function from terminating before goroutines finish in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752705/prevent-the-main-function-from-terminating-before-goroutines-finish-in-golang/42753005#42753005) and [Solving goroutines deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865561/solving-goroutines-deadlock/48866810#48866810).

Also registering a `defer` function at the end of `main()` to "catch" panics has no effect:

```
   defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println(r)
        }
    }()
```

This should be the first (or an earlier but definitely not the last) call in `main()`. Also if you just print the error, it's needless as a panic not recovered from will also be printed. Use `recover()` if you intend to handle the situation.

Also in `readFile()` when reading from the file, you should also check for `io.EOF`, as the file may not have as many lines as you expect it to, in which case you may break early.

Comment: thanks for all the help, specially the other subtleties you mentioned.