# How to fix 2 channels dead lock each other

Tags: go, locking, channel

I have this piece of Go code. I need to have this ability: write into channels in one place, and read them out in another place(or vice versa):

```
package main
import "fmt"
var ch1=make(chan int)
var ch2=make(chan int)

func f1() {
    select {
    case <- ch1:fmt.Println("ch1")
    default: fmt.Println("default")
    }
}
func f2() {
    select {
    case <- ch2:fmt.Println("ch2")
    default: fmt.Println("default")
    }
}
func main() {
    go f1()
    go f2()
    ch1<-1
    ch2<-2
}
```

It always prints sth like this:

```
default
ch1
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox970110849/prog.go:22 +0xa0
```

Further more I tried this:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)
var ch1=make(chan int)
var ch2=make(chan int)

func f1() {
    select {
    case <- ch1:fmt.Println("ch1")
    default: fmt.Println("default")
    }
}
func f2() {
    select {
    case <- ch2:fmt.Println("ch2")
    default: fmt.Println("default")
    }
}

func w1() {
    ch1 <-1
}

func w2() {
    ch2 <-1
}
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(4)
    go f1()
    go f2()
    go w1()
    go w2()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Even more errors this time:

```
default
ch2
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x40e028, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x40
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x40e020, 0x14b720)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x60
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox916639182/prog.go:36 +0x100

goroutine 8 [chan send]:
main.w1()
    /tmp/sandbox916639182/prog.go:23 +0x40
created by main.main
    /tmp/sandbox916639182/prog.go:34 +0xc0
```

Where did I go wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve (besides getting rid of deadlock)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `main()` function tries to send on all channels, and there is only a one-time attempt to read from those channels in separate, concurrent goroutines. It's up to the goroutine scheduler if this will succeed. If the non-blocking receive in `f2()` is scheduled earlier than the send in `main()`, then the later send in `main()` will block forever (no one will attempt to receive from `ch2` again).

One way to get rid of the deadlock is to use receive operation instead of the non-blocking receive (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/X6yM0j5HOfU)):

```
func f1() {
    <-ch1
    fmt.Println("ch1")
}
func f2() {
    <-ch2
    fmt.Println("ch2")
}
```

So no matter when `main()` gets to the point to send values on these channels, there will always be a receiver ready to proceed, so the `main()` won't get stuck.

Note that when `main()` returns, the app ends, it does not wait for non-main goroutines to finish. So you might not see `ch1` and `ch2` printed on your console. For details, see [No output from goroutine in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958192/no-output-from-goroutine-in-go/28958240#28958240).

If your intent is to wait for all goroutines to finish their work before your app exists, use `sync.WaitGroup` for that (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PE7kqAjM1Wy)):

```
var ch1 = make(chan int)
var ch2 = make(chan int)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func f1() {
    defer wg.Done()
    <-ch1
    fmt.Println("ch1")
}

func f2() {
    defer wg.Done()
    <-ch2
    fmt.Println("ch2")
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go f1()
    wg.Add(1)
    go f2()

    ch1 <- 1
    ch2 <- 2
    wg.Wait()
}
```

See more examples here: [Solving goroutines deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865561/solving-goroutines-deadlock/48866810#48866810); and [Prevent the main() function from terminating before goroutines finish in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752705/prevent-the-main-function-from-terminating-before-goroutines-finish-in-golang/42753005#42753005).

Another option is to give a buffer of 1 to the channels, so the `main()` can send 1 value on them without a receiver ready to receive from the channels (try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LE8L2m9kbPR)):

```
var ch1 = make(chan int, 1)
var ch2 = make(chan int, 1)
```

With this the `main()` can proceed without `f1()` and `f2()`, so again, there is no guarantee you will see anything printed.

Answer (score 3):

> Channels used here are unbuffered channels.

- when main goroutines starts it creates two new goroutine f1 and f2.
- when f1 or f2 is executed it will check whether we have value in the channel else it will print the default message and exit.
- In ideal situation,channels will be published with value first and then it's is received via the goroutine
- Actual situation is that goroutines are exiting by printing the default case but main goroutine is trying to publish value in a channel but since no receiver is there it faces a deadlock situation.

> Removed deadlock from first example,
>   Refer the link:https://play.golang.org/p/6RuQQwC9JkA

However,if main routine exits all the associated goroutines will be killed automatically.
That's why we can see that value is printed arbitrarily.

> Removed deadlock from Second example,
>   Refer the link:https://play.golang.org/p/yUmc_jjZMgV

sync.WaitGroup is making main goroutine wait that's why we can observe the output everytime our program executes.